# How to deploy a WordPress Theme that is using webpack for bundling?

Tags: wordpress, webpack, deployment, bundle

I used to developed WordPress themes in the early 2010's but I am now really out of fashion, especially with things like `Webpack` and `npm`.

I am following a tutorial and I have already finished my theme. `Webpack` bundles an **assets** folder with the production files. However, the **src** folder, `package-lock.json` and `webpack.config.js` are still in the root folder.

I know by common sense, but not pretty sure, that those files shouldn't be there since that's the reason of the bundling process. How do I distribute my template and further plugins or even React apps without sharing de **src** files and only the bundled and minified ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the awesome tutorial for using Webpack and WordPress together.

https://wptips.dev/webpack-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for pointed out that website, the tuts I've been follow already taught me this. However it is a pleasure to have it written down and so well summarized. Should I distribute also src files after npm run prod once I've finished?